# Val_loss is very high (over 100)

Tags: image-processing, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to create a neural network for image classification. This is my [Model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Di3R.png). I have done normalization to my dataset and shuffling to my data.
 . When I run model.fit the val_loss is very high sometimes close to 100 whereas my loss is less than 0.8

Comment: did you implement preprocessing only for training data and not for validation data? Are you doing custom training or using `model.fit`?

Comment: I did convert(image,dtype.float32) to my training data and then divided by 255. For test data, i just divided by 255. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't normalize test data, validation loss will be very high when compared to training data that was normalized. I used simple mnist model to demonstrate the point of normalization.

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# this is to demonstrate the importance of normalizing both training and testing data
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 1.
```

When we don't normalize test data where as training data was normalized,
training loss is `loss: 0.0771` where as loss during test is `13.1599`. Please check the complete [code here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/mnist_test_data_not_normalized.ipynb). Thanks!

Comment: I did the x_test/255 but I didnt convert it into float32 first. Thanks.

Comment: you could also do `x_test/255.0 or x_test/255. But, it is better to cast it like `x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255`. Thanks!